# Crystal Report error Database Vendor Code 18456 force password

Tags: sql, sql-server, crystal-reports

I'm having an error of 18456 while trying to export a report using an existing application that use the Crystal Report Viewer.
From what i've found, this error means that the SQL is failing to logon with the user and password

In this site it says that you can use an udl file to force the password in the connection.
https://jwcooney.com/2011/10/03/crystal-reports-generating-sql-server-error-18456-severity-8-error-logs/

But that doesn't work, so how can i configure the rpt file to export a report, that access a sql server that has a password?

Answer (score 0):

So i found the solution, is a login problem in the SQL side, from what i found in
[Embed SQL Password into Crystal Reports RPT file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2730550/embed-sql-password-into-crystal-reports-rpt-file?rq=1)

"Connect to a "ODBC (RDO)" via "Create Connection" in Crystal Reports. At the bottom of the dialog you'll find an option to enter a connection string. A connection string can contain the login info, like the example below.

Example connection string: DSN=;DB=;UID=;PWD=password"
you can create dsn file with the password included and make a connection with that file